# how to install 'amnah / yii2' in Yii 2.0?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How can i do this?
Despite my attempts I couldn't. I don't understand amnah's document. 
On the document;
"
    Install Yii 2 using your preferred method
    Install package via composer "amnah/yii2-user": "~2.0"
    Update config file config/web.php and config/db.php
"

But I could not use to composer.
Can you tell me, how can I do manual install?

**Solved:**

Well, I added "amnah/yii2-user": "dev-master" in "require" on composer.json file. Then "composer update" and work.

Comment: Learn to use composer, you just have to edit the file composer.json, add the text, then preform an `composer update`. You can of course install it by hand but you will get a lot more by learning to use composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use **composer**, you can just download the library you need and then place it under the `vendor/` directory, in your project's root.

For example, if you want to use **phpspec/php-diff** in your project, you can download the project yourself (from **github**) and then put it into `vendor/`. It should look like this:

```
|--myproject
   |--commands
   |--config
   |--controllers
   ...
   |--vendor
      |--phpspec
         |--php-diff
```

This is basically what composer does when you install something via composer.

Comment: I'm telling what doing;
I downloaded "amnah / yii2-user" here : https://github.com/amnah/yii2-user;
After, i copied yii2-user folder to "vendor". 
After, i went to  myproject/basic folder. i was right click over composer.json file. i was click "composer update" in right click menu. i can't take result. İt's answer; no matching package found.
what will i do now? :(

Comment: If you manually download the library, you can't use composer to update library! Use only one of both methods @Serhat

Comment: i did this with composer. i can see, this is ok: http://imgur.com/T5fREfo . But it's not working.it can't see file by amnah. Not amnah user controllers. :/

Comment: Everything is ok. I solved. Thanks for everything :)

Comment: @Serhat please edit your question detailing solution or add an answer detailing how you solved

Comment: Well, i added "amnah/yii2-user": "dev-master" in "require" in composer.json file. After Composer update. I did like this.